# Programmatically add Event to Sharepoint Calendar using Client OM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, calendar

I need to programmatically add events to a SharePoint Calendar and make them repeatable using JavaScript Client Object Model (without any c# code).
Does anybody have ideas how can I implement this using ClientContext js class?
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Calendar");
    var newEventCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newEvent = list.addItem(newEventCreateInfo);
    newEvent.set_item("Location", "Office");
    newEvent.set_item("Start Time", "Start Time of JS Date() type");
    newEvent.set_item("End Time","End Time of JS Date() type");
    newEvent.set_item("Description","Discussion about Calendar JSCOM");
    newEvent.set_item("Title","New Discussion");
    newEvent.set_item("fAllDayEvent",false);
    newEvent.set_item("Category","Discussion");
    newEvent.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){ alert("Success");},function(){ alert("Failure");})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the article for details how to add item to sharepoint list using js Client Object Model - http://www.avanadeblog.com/sharepointasg/2011/05/client-object-model-introduction-part-2-adding-a-list-item.html